# Getting SIGSEGV error if I remove a particular cout statement

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<string> splitter(string s)
{
    vector<string>v;
    int start=0;
    int end=0;
    while(end<s.length())
    {
        while(s[end]!=' ')
        {
            end++;
        }
        v.push_back(s.substr(start, end-start));
        end++;
        start=end;
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    // Write your code here
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout<<"here";//Getting SIGSEGV error if this line is removed
    vector<string> v=splitter(s);
    map<string, int> m;
    int flag=1;
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        m[v[i]]+=1;
    }
    map<string, int>::iterator it;
    for(it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); it++)
    {
        string name=it->first;
        int freq=it->second;
        if(freq>1)
        {
            flag=0;
            cout<<name<<" "<<freq<<endl;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1){
        cout<<"-1";
    }
}
```

I'm using an online compiler in a coding platform. If I remove the cout<<"Here"; statement, the compiler throws SIGSEGV error. The splitter() functions works fine. I am encountering this error only for a specific testcase. The result printed is valid if I add the cout statement for that case too.

Comment: The inner loop causes undefined behavior, end goes out of the string.

Comment: Have you tried either sanitizers or Valgrind? Even just running your code in a debugger should help pinpoint the issue. You don't say which platform this is on, so these may not be appropriate.

Comment: Think about `splitter` if you give it `"a"`. When does `while(s[end]!=' ') { end++; }` stop? (Appearing to work fine is the most evil form of undefined behaviour.)